# Best Way to Handle Repeated API Queries With Data Limit Restrictions

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm working with eBay API and in particular a GetMultipleItems call which feeds the api query with a list of item ID's to return data. The problem i'm facing is that the API has a limit per query of 20 item id's.  I'm making call in my backend in node and returning the data via React and Redux.

This is where i make the call to my action creator in React front end.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    props.getUpdates(formatFavs);
  }, [props.favorites]);
```

Note that `formatFavs` is a list of comma separated itemID's

Here is my getUpdates action creator

```
export const getUpdates = id => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const updates = await dataService.getMultiple(id);
    dispatch({
      type: "GET_DATA",
      data: updates
    });
  };
};
```

Which is pointing to my axios call to the backend.

```
const getMultiple = query => {
  const request = axios.get(baseUrl + `?id=${query}`);
  console.log("URL", baseUrl + `?id=${query}`);
  console.log("Request", request);
  return request.then(response => response.data);
};
```

This is what the resulting call looks like

`https://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetMultipleItems&appid=XX&responseencoding=JSON&ItemID=231560863628,223787055529,392521444227,352879382550,274129160671,274129160671,274129160671,123998356843,223787055529,383011548243,223787055529,392521444227,352879382550,123998356843,274129160671,133268486829,223787404912`'

Currently if there are more than 20 id's it generates an error on the API end.

I need to figure out how to handle any situation where there are more than 20 id's

My initial line of thinking is to put a conditional statement at the start of my `getMultiple` call.

something like

```
if query.length >20 {
   newQuery = query.slice(1,19) 
   const request = axios.get(baseUrl + `id=${newQuery}
   return request.then(response => response.data)
 }
```

although i'm not sure where to go from here...just looking for some suggestions as I'm struggling to come up with the right solution

UPDATED--got this working based on Kostas guidance. Here is the code:

```
import axios from "axios";
const baseUrl = "/getMultiple";

async function getMultiple(query) {
  if (query.length < 21) {
    const request = axios.get(baseUrl + `?id=${query}`);
    return request.then(response => response.data);
  }

  let ids = [...query];
  console.log("IDS", ids);
  const batchSize = 20;
  const requests = [];

  while (ids.length) {
    let currentBatch = ids.splice(0, batchSize);
    console.log("Current batch", currentBatch);
    requests.push(axios.get(baseUrl + `?id=${currentBatch}`));
  }

  console.log("Requests", requests);

  const final = await Promise.all(requests);
  const finalData = final.map(dataArray => dataArray.data);
  const arrayData = Array.prototype.concat(...finalData);

  return arrayData;
}

export default {
  getMultiple
};
```

Comment: 20 items per query or 20 items then you have to wait some amount of time before you can execute another query?

Comment: Maybe breaking up the query (with more than 20 IDs) into multiple requests and using Promise.all() to get back the aggregated results?

Comment: 20 items per query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break the request into multiple batches and use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to get back the result as follows:

```js
async function getMultiple( input ) {

    if ( input.length < 21 ){
        return axios.get( baseUrl + `id=${input}` );
    } 

    let ids = [ ...input ];
    const batchSize = 20;  
    const requests = [];

    while ( ids.length ){

        let currentBatch = ids.splice( 0, batchSize );
        requests.push( axios.get( baseUrl + `id=${currentBatch}` ) );    

    }

    return await Promise.all( requests );

}
let input = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 24, 25, 25 ];

getMultiple( input ).then( res => console.log(res) );
```

Comment: thanks man, this looks great, i think this will do the trick, much appreciated

Comment: kostas, one quick question on this!  the Promise.all is returning an object of arrays for each request.  i just need the data array from each request.  is there a best way to grab the combined 'data' arrays from each in a combined array with the way the promise is structured?

Comment: I think, the [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method will help you here.

Comment: YEP, i'm going to add my working code to my question, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would break up your calls and group them into a `Promise` array. `axios.get` returns a `Promise` so you can use that in place of the example function (`httpGet(id)`)

Basically, create a method to receive *n* number of favorites. Then, break down your ids into groups of 20 with your `axios` calls. So, if you received 60 ids, you'd end up with 3 api calls (each with 20 ids).

You can then get the entire result list in the return of `Promise.all` and concat the array from there (if you need to). Below, I'm not grouping your ids by 20 but rather demonstrating the usage of how you can leverage `Promise.all` to send a bunch of and wait for all of them to resolve and do something with that result.

```js
function httpGet(id) {
  return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
    .then(response => response.json());
}

function getFavorites(ids) {
  // TODO: Implement logic to group promise array by chunks of 20
  const promises = ids.map(id => httpGet(id));
  return Promise.all(promises);

}

getFavorites([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]).then(results => console.log(results));
```